# Remove an event listener that was added from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, removeeventlistener

I can't use removeEventListener on document via a button in my chrome extension.

I've had a good read about isolated worlds but I can't understand exactly what I'm supposed to do here. I'm not even sure that the popup script also is subject to an isolated world context?

I'm checking for the existence of a hidden field. When that hidden field is detected, the code is supposed to remove the event listener, but it's like it doesn't exist. This is my popup.js:

```
function toggle_clare(){      
if(!document.getElementById("clare_on")){ //check for existence of hidden field

var clare_status = document.createElement("input");
    clare_status.type = "hidden";
    clare_status.id = "clare_on";
    clare_status.value = "on";

document.body.appendChild(clare_status); //add it to document if doesn't exist

document.addEventListener("keyup", read_out, true); //add keyup listener

return clare_status.value; //send "on" to the button in the popup
}

else if(document.getElementById("clare_on")){ //alread exists
    var off = "off";

    $("#clare_on").remove();//remove the hidden field

    document.removeEventListener("keyup", read_out, true);//not working

    return off; // send "off" to the button
   }
}

//Function call

document.getElementById( "clare_button" ).addEventListener( "click", 
function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: '(' + toggle_clare + ')()'
    }, ( results ) => { // receive "on" or "off" from toggle_clare function

            document.getElementById("clare_button").innerText = "Clare is now " + results[0];

    })
})
```

I was expecting this to remove the event listener when the hidden field is removed. ALL of this code works except removeEventListener.

Comment: Without looking at your manifest.json I'd say you don't understand the architecture of extensions. The content script runs in a tab, while the popup script runs in a separate popup page not related to the tab. These are two separate unconnected pages each with its own DOM and `document`.

Comment: While I'm certainly no expert on architecture, I understand enough to know that using chrome.tabs.executeScript should get round the isolated world issue (or maybe I'm being too hopeful.) My manifest is set up to cope with this too. 

I've also noticed that running "monitorEvents($0)" in console against the #document root doesn't display the keyup event listener I've added.

Comment: No, executeScript actually runs a content script in the web page tab and does it precisely inside the isolated world (because it's where all content script run). Without seeing manifst.json or, better yet, [MCVE](/help/mcve), the posted code does something weird or plain wrong so I can't help further.

Comment: Awesome thanks! At least that puts me in the right direction.